# 403 Forbidden (Springboot and Angular)

Tags: angular, spring-boot

I am creating a portfolio web for a final project with SpringBoot and Angular, but I have been having lots of problems with it.

Everything works perfect on localhost but when I do the deploy on Render (back), the data is not shown on the front.

This is the MainSecurity:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class MainSecurity extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    UserDetailsImpl userDetailsServicesImpl;

    @Autowired
    JwtEntryPoint jwtEntryPoint;

    @Bean
    public JwtTokenFilter jwtTokenFilter() {
        return new JwtTokenFilter();
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.cors().and().csrf().disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(jwtEntryPoint)
                .and()
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
        http.addFilterBefore(jwtTokenFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }

    @Override
    protected AuthenticationManager authenticationManager() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManager();
    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsServicesImpl).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're running into a CORS error, meaning the domain of the frontend doesn't match the one of the backend.

This requires you to add the frontend domain to allowed origins on your backend. (for adding allowed domains, you should differentiate between a local / dev and production environment of the server).

You can learn more about CORS [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS).

Answer (score 0):

You can try by adding `allowCredentials="true"`

what will give us

```
@CrossOrigin(origins ="https://frontjds.web.app", maxAge = 3600, allowCredentials="true")
```

And if you want ta add many origins

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = {"http://localhost:4200","http://localhost:8200","http://localhost:8100","otherlink"}, maxAge = 3600, allowCredentials="true")
```

> And it's not very convenient to use "*"